# Double Java Stream not leaving when wanted

Tags: java, dictionary, steam, collect

Here is my problem.

```
public LinkedHashSet<Quiz> findAllQuizByCompanyAndCategory(List<QuizCompany> quizList, String quizCategoryId) {
    int i = 1;
    return hibernateQuizJpaRepository
                 .findAllByCategorySetContaining(new HibernateQuizCategory(quizCategoryId))
                 .stream()
                 .filter(current -> quizList.stream()
                 .anyMatch(quiz -> Objects.equals(current.getId(), quiz.getQuizId())))
                 .map(HibernateQuiz::toQuiz)
                 .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));
 }
```

As you can see on the screen the quizId and the id are the same on the anymatch.
But it will never enter in the map. Does anyone have an idea why?

Removed breakpoints because the issue has been solved

Comment: We can see your code, but what is the problem?

Comment: A problem is not a block a code, a problem is an explanation of expected output and given output, so please update your post

Comment: done sorry i eddited the post

Comment: Are you sure `equals` is returning true? There could be some non-printable characters.

Comment: just checked the value and the hash, looks like it's the same

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Comment: @JulesSpender Just because the issue is solved, doesn't invalidate the breakpoints. That's still considered vandalism. Is there a reason why you keep removing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use String.intern on

```
    current.getId().intern()
```

and

```
  quiz.getQuizId().intern()
```